# Properly working on Git sub branch for merging it later with Master

Tags: git, github

I am part of a small team working on a web development project. I was asked to work on a new feature of the project whose SVN is maintained on GitHub. So, I created a new branch for this purpose and pushing my changes to this branch. While my team mates work on Master . So, what I do is I pull frequently from master and push changes to my branch. Is this correct way if we want to merge my branch with the master?

Additionally, When I commit using Tortoise git software, it automatically merges Master branch into my subbranch. Like in this picture. Black is the master , blue is the subbranch. Did it(Tortoise Git software) actually merge Master with my branch? I was specifically asked to work on my own branch!

[image]

I am new to github. Is there any simple tutorial that you can suggest ? Few months back I have seen a web application (hosted on github) that help you learn Git step by step (Typing commands and visualizing it on a animation alongside)

Comment: Read http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching and use http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/. Fix your terminology. What you call a "tree" is called a "branch". What you call a "SVN" is called a "Git repository". You typically rebase your branch on top of master until it's ready to be merged back into master.

Comment: It could also be that by "tree" the OP actually meant a clone...

Also, this is probably the "web application" the OP was referring to: https://try.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pull from master frequently. Just work on your branch and then commit & push all changes to your branch. Later merge it with master. That is why you are one commit ahead of master.

Here is a good hands on tutorial on GIT branching

http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You only need to merge from master to your branch if some of your teammates makes a change that you NEED on your branch (i.e. some bug fix that interferes with your work or something critical)

Otherwise there's no point in doing this, as your changes are going to be merged back to master later..